# Can I redirect to a valid Wicket page when attempting to access a non-existent page?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, wicket, http-status-code-404

**Introduction**

If a user of my Apache Wicket web application (which runs on GAE/J) attempts to visit a non-existent page, for example:

```
http://[MyURL]/admin/PageSubscribeX
```

the web framework logs the following warning:

```
org.apache.wicket.core.util.lang.WicketObjects resolveClass: Could not resolve class [[...].admin.PageSubscribeX]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: [...].admin.PageSubscribeX
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-78915baf06af5f31(Request.java)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:133)
    at org.apache.wicket.application.AbstractClassResolver.resolveClass(AbstractClassResolver.java:108)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.util.lang.WicketObjects.resolveClass(WicketObjects.java:71)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.mapper.AbstractComponentMapper.getPageClass(AbstractComponentMapper.java:139)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.mapper.PackageMapper.parseRequest(PackageMapper.java:148)
    ...
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:458)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

and GAE/J responds with an error 404 page and the text `Error: NOT_FOUND`.

I know that currently with GAE/J I "cannot customize the 404 response page when no servlet mapping is defined for a URL".

**My question**

Is there any way I can specify a Wicket page for the response when no servlet mapping is defined for a URL? Alternatively, is there some servlet mapping I can define to map "all URLs not found" to a Wicket page of my choice?

My software environment is:

- Wicket: 6.2.0
- GAE/J: 1.7.3
- Java: 1.6.0_37.

**A failed attempt**

Following the comments of @biziclop, I have tried the following, but this failed. All I got was my error page PageError showing every time....

My code in my `WebApplication#init()` was:

```
ICompoundRequestMapper crmRoot = getRootRequestMapperAsCompound();
URLNotFoundMapper mapperURLNotFound = new URLNotFoundMapper(null,
 PageError.class);
crmRoot.add(mapperURLNotFound);
setRootRequestMapper(crmRoot);
```

My new mapper `URLNotFoundMapper` was

```
/**
 * This mapper class is intended to be the mapper of last resort, to be used
 * if all other mappers cannot handle the URL of the current request.
 * <br/>
 * This mapper will cause a defined (error) page to be shown.
 */
public class URLNotFoundMapper extends BookmarkableMapper
{
  private IRequestMapper m_rmRoot = null;
  private Class<? extends IRequestablePage> m_classPage = null;

  /**
   * Constructor.
   * @param rmRoot
   *   The application's previous root request mapper.
   *   If this is <code>null</code> then it is ignored.
   * @param clError
   *   The class of the page which should handle erroneous requests.
   *   This must not be <code>null</code>.
   */
  public URLNotFoundMapper(IRequestMapper rmRoot,
   final Class<? extends IRequestablePage> clError)
  {
    m_rmRoot = rmRoot;
    m_classPage = clError;
  }

  /**
   * Use this mapper as the last option.
   * So let all other mappers try to handle the request first.
   * @param request
   *   The request.
   * @return
   *   The score of the application's previous root request mapper.
   */
  @Override
  public int getCompatibilityScore(Request request)
  {
    return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
  }

  /**
   * This method returns an <code>IRequestHandler</code> for the bookmarkable
   * error page.
   * @param request
   * @return
   *   An <code>IRequestHandler</code> capable of processing a bookmarkable
   *   request.
   *
   */
  @Override
  public IRequestHandler mapRequest(Request request)
  {
    IRequestHandler rhResult = null;
    if (m_rmRoot != null)
      rhResult = m_rmRoot.mapRequest(request);

    if (rhResult != null)
      rhResult = null;    // Another mapper can handle this
    else
    {
      rhResult = processBookmarkable(m_classPage, null);
    }

    return rhResult;
  }

  @Override
  public Url mapHandler(IRequestHandler requestHandler)
  {
    Url urlResult = null;
    if (m_rmRoot != null)
      urlResult = m_rmRoot.mapHandler(requestHandler);

    if (urlResult != null)
      urlResult = null;    // Another mapper can handle this
    else
    {
      PageInfo info = new PageInfo();
      UrlInfo urlInfo = new UrlInfo(new PageComponentInfo(info, null),
       m_classPage, null);
      urlResult = buildUrl(urlInfo);
    }

    return urlResult;
  }

  /**
   * @return
   *   The URL info for the bookmarkable error page.
   */
  @Override
  protected UrlInfo parseRequest(Request request)
  {
    UrlInfo uiResult = null;
    uiResult = new UrlInfo(null, m_classPage, null);
    return uiResult;
  }
}
```

Comment: It should certainly be possible and looking at the stack trace I think it's probably best to deal with this on the mapper level.

Comment: @biziclop Do you mean by amending my web.xml file to include an "error-page" element, or something else?

Comment: I meant programmatically, as it's done [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/request-mapping.html). In the last code snippet they show you how to replace the root request mapper with a custom implementation. From there you have full control over which page class you're trying to load and when.

Comment: @biziclop Thanks anyway for that, but my attempts at using a mapper to intercept erroneous URLs have failed.

Answer (score 3):

you need to configure the 404 http error in your webapp, take a look [here](http://www.mkyong.com/wicket/how-do-configure-404-error-page-in-wicket-solution)

The questioner's extract from the link above is:

```
<error-page>
  <error-code>404</error-code>
  <location>/[URI portion to point to a customer error page]</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: Sadly, Google App Engine for Java (GAE/J) does not allow this solution using a web.xml file "error-page" element for error code 404. (In practice, this config is ignored.) Can you or anyone else think of another solution?

Comment: O.o, you could override the error page of wicket but that just gonna work for server internel errors(runtime exceptions), for the 404 http error As far i know always is server configuration