# Wicket mount a 404 error page

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-1.5

Is there way to mount a 404 error page in **Wicket-1.5.x** without adding:

```
<error-page> 
  <error-code>404</error-code>
  <location>/NotFound</location>
</error-page>
```

to my web.xml file?

I have several applications that all use the same/similar Look/Feel.  I've extracted out a lot of the common functionality including my error pages to some shared jar files.  I'm already mounting a lot of common pages (Login Pages, Error Pages, etc) via an [Iinitializer](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/IInitializer.html).  Is there a way I can do the same for `404` errors?

**UPDATE:**

In Doing more research I also found this question:
[Can I redirect to a valid Wicket page when attempting to access a non-existent page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477568/can-i-redirect-to-a-valid-wicket-page-when-attempting-to-access-a-non-existent-p)
Which also seems to state that editing `web.xml` is the solution.

As I said I have several applications while editing the file isn't hard and there isn't *that* many, it's one more thing I'll have to remember next time I upgrade them.

If it makes a difference I'm using **Tomcat-6.x** Is there possibly a way to *fake* the `<error-page>` configuration setting in my `web.xml` by modifying `ServletContext`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you need those lines in your web.xml, but once you've done that you can still mount your common page along with everything else in your `IInitializer`:

```
application.mount(
        new QueryStringUrlCodingStrategy("NotFound", NotFoundErrorPage.class));
```